# I am trying to find the defects in following images. Not sure where to begin

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

`[This has color defect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XtOY.png)

[This has crack defect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37NLf.png)

[This has scratch defect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbr8C.png)

[This has imprinting defect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An39B.png)

input_img = cv2.resize(input_img,(500,500),interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

gray_i_image = cv2.cvtColor(input_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blur_image = cv2.blur(gray_i_image,(3,3))

`

This is what I know in which I am resizing the image, then converting it to grey scale and then clearing the noise from data image. After that I don't know what to do.

I want an output image in which the defected area is highlighted as in rectangle, I know we have to use contours for it. but I dont know how to.

Comment: Besides the "color" defect, the other defects cannot be seen where there is color. This is for sure. So start by masking out the colored areas. Then binarization (possibly adaptive) will work to some extent. (Also check if registration is needed.)

Comment: The scratch defect is barely visible, maybe play with illumination.

Comment: On Stackoverflow it is more likely to get a good answer if you ask for one specific programming question rather than how to solve a whole project. You can start e.g. with the colour defect, present what you already have tried and where exactly you got stuck. Please read [ask],